# Error when deploying .war to tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have written a jax-ws web service and I am trying to deploy it in tomcat server. The JAX-RS implementation jars are copied into the lib folder of my web service project.

Following is the log file output of catalina.out

```
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /home/fazlan/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/Simple.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Simple]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
  version="2.0">
  <endpoint
      name="Dog"
      implementation="com.fazlan.ws.Dog"
      url-pattern="/bark"/>
</endpoints>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, 
Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Dog</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Dog</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/bark</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Do you have more exceptions in other logs?

Comment: can you tell me which logs should i look into?

Comment: All logfiles in tamcat/logs